# dotnet nuke error

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

Hi there i am trying to debug a dot net nuke server error and iam not sure where to start. I don't have the code locally else I could debug (no that i am familiar the `dnn` setup).

This bug affects making `cms` updates to the site with the message **'A critical error has occurred'**,

I have been unsuccessfully trying to find out the cause and i am finally throwing up my hands,

I don't even  need a fix , I just want to find out what is causing the error so I can provide an estimate for a fix and I can even seem to do that. Please Help!!

Comment: have you checked the DNN event log?

Comment: that was my initial thought , Im new to DNN, the log table is quite huge, will get back you

Answer (score 2):

If you head over to the menu in DotNetNuke under Admin | Event Viewer/Log and drill down with the supplied drop down lists, that will get you somewhere.

Choose the Portal and Type, you might want to choose General Exception for Type to begin with unless you've spotted a hint when it bombs out.